# Cassandra select order by

Tags: cassandra, cql

I create table as this

```
CREATE TABLE sm.data (
    did int,
    tid int,
    ts timestamp,
    aval text,
    dval decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY (did, tid, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (tid ASC, ts DESC);
```

Before I did all select query with ts DESC so it was good. Now I also need select query with ts ASC in some cases. How do I accomplish that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply use ORDER BY ts ASC**

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE did = ? and tid = ? ORDER BY ts ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do this select

**select * from data where did=1 and tid=2 order by ts asc;**

you will end up with some errors

**InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by currently only support the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY"**

I have tested it against my local cassandra db 
I would suggets altering the order of the primary key columns

the reason is that :
**"Querying compound primary keys and sorting results ORDER BY clauses can select a single column only. That column has to be the second column in a compound PRIMARY KEY."**

CREATE TABLE data2 (
    did int,
    tid int,
    ts timestamp,
    aval text,
    dval decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY (did, ts, tid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC, tid ASC)

**Now we are free to choose the type of ordering for TS**

cassandra@cqlsh:airline> SELECT * FROM data2 WHERE did = 1 and ts=2 order by ts DESC;

did | ts | tid | aval | dval
-----+----+-----+------+------

(0 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:airline> SELECT * FROM data2 WHERE did = 1 and ts=2 order by ts ASC;

did | ts | tid | aval | dval
-----+----+-----+------+------

(0 rows)

Another way would be either to create a new table or a materialized view , the later would lead behind the scene to data duplication anyway 
hope that clear enough